# Is there a word for "love of open spaces"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As distinct from "love for public spaces" which I understand *agoraphilia* to mean. Since I think the Greek *agora* means an "assembly" or "market place"; not "open spaces".

Comment: Agoraphilia is alright.

Comment: @vickyace I think you'd better look up the term before possibly leading OP into trouble.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand what you're saying. It can be used in situations when an alternate interpretation is possible.

Comment: @vickyace Anyone can use words or 'words' any way they want. But I can't find any supporting evidence that 'agoraphilia' would be assumed to mean / has been used to mean 'a love of open spaces', and the evidence I _have_ found supports the view that it would be assumed to have the meaning psychologists give it if anything.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What about this approach: If two people are aware of the word **agoraphobia**, but nor **agoraphilia**, they would immediately interpret it to be the way OP asked. If they aren't aware of either, they'd figure it out if they learn of the meanings of the root words independently. Psychologists have ruined a good word. Caveat for the OP - user discretion is advised.

Comment: @vickyace English is not completely productive. To _telescope_ doesn't mean to observe with or use a telescope. ELU looks at English usage, not Utopian English (X's version, of course).

Comment: Got to agree with @EdwinAshworth here. There just doesn't seem to be such a one-word in English. Which is fine, really.

Comment: As a person who feels at home only above timberline in the Sierra or Rocky mountains, I say with some certainty that there is no single word to express what I feel there.  Sailors, tundra dwellers and desert dwellers probably feel the same.

Answer (score 2):

If by "open spaces" you mean areas away from buildings, a possibility is *outdoorsy*.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/outdoorsy)

> unusually fond of outdoor life:
>   *an outdoorsy type who always swam before breakfast.*

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outdoorsy):

> Of, associated with, or fond of the outdoors.
>   *‘Bill is such an outdoorsy kind of guy’*

Comment: This seems more specific. As in it seems defined in opposition to indoors. Instead of being opposed to confined spaces.

Comment: Claustrophobia is the fear of confined spaces, so I guess it could also be the love of non-confined spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Kenomania? Or kenophilia? Both came up when looking into this.