# Is there a term for ' the need to be in open spaces'?

Tags: phrases

After living in NM for most of my life, coming to Vermont is a challenge. I tried to describe it, the physical and emotional need to see horizons, open space, expansive vistas and how the dense trees, forests and hills are claustrophobic for me. Is there a way to say that without the whole explanation?

Comment: Look up the term "agoraphobia." It may not apply to you, of course, but what you're experiencing may be mildly related. I'm just the opposite -- I find the wide horizons of the midwest overwhelmingly depressing.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is what I feel: The need for the night sky.  You know what I mean, I think.  But I don't know how to explain that concisely to someone who has never seen the night sky in all its glory.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard The OP has the opposite of agoraphobia.    See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385012/is-there-a-word-for-love-of-open-spaces.  And the word is not agoraphilia.  I doubt a word in English exists.  Possibly in Arabic or a language of desert dwellers?

Comment: I'm hearing cabin fever and don't fence me in.

Comment: I just came across the word kenomania/ kenophilia. See what you think. And thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Consider *cenomania*.

> **cenomania** *noun*
>   A strong desire to be in open, barren, and empty places away from other people.
>   [- wordinfo](http://wordinfo.info/results/cenomania)

The etymology suggests a desire for the 'common', like the word "cenobite", which uses "life in common" to define the lives of monks.

Comment: +1 That was a good find! I've edited your answer to add a link and quote, as well as for presentation and clarity. Please feel free to edit further or to roll it back.